# How to move to a certain character from right to left of line in Vim

Tags: vim

```
This is a sentence
```

If the cursor is on `s` of `This`, I want to move the cursor on `n` of `sentence`

I can do <kbd>$</kbd><kbd>F</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>

But this can't be used combining with other command like `delete`

e.g If the cursor is on `s` of `This`, and delete all between cursor and `n` of `sentence`

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>F</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> doesn't work

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [JumpToLastOccurrence plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3386) extends the built-in f/F/t/T motions with counterparts that move to the last occurrence of `{char}` in the line. Your example would be `d,fn`.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you have trouble with deleting words between `s` and the second `n` in "sentence". You can do it by

```
d2fn
```

And as @kev mentioned, `easymotion` is a good choice, with `easymotion` you can do it in a more intuitive way like

```
d<Leader><Leader>fn
```

the above command will highlight `n` in the line and let you choose.

Answer (score 1):

Vim plugin [`easymotion`](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion) can help you.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you can use the search command `/` in combination with the `d` command to delete up to a pattern match.

But, you can also make use of search offsets to place the cursor anywhere you want in relation to that search. See `:help search-offset` for details, but in your case:

`d/senten/e` will delete up to and including the second 'n' in "sentence".

You could also use `d/sentence/e-2` to do the same thing but limit the match even more.

This is very powerful in combination with incremental search and search highlighting, because then you can see exactly what you're acting on before you hit `<Enter>` to finish the command, or `<Esc>` or `<C-C>` to cancel the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use visual mode: `v$Fnd`

Answer (score 1):

My Vim plugin [ft_improved](https://github.com/chrisbra/improvedft) can also help. You simply keep on typing until the match is unique.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do the task with your plugin?

Comment: You need to set `let g:ft_improved_multichars = 1`. Then press `f` then type `n`, note how all matching *n* will be highlighted. Keep on typing, until the match is unique. It will jump you to the second `n`.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know which “n” in “sentence” is referred to here, but you can indeed use `d` to do this. Simply combine it with search (`/`):

```
d/n
```

Or, if you want to delete up to the second “n” in “sentence”, you could make the search pattern one character more specific:

```
d/nc
```